# URI is not registered in values.xml

Tags: android, xml

I got error in `values.xml URI is not Registered` and Build failed due to

> Error:(729, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'listTextColor'.
>
> Error:(728, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorMain'.
>
> Error:(728, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorMain'.
>
> Error:(729, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'listTextColor'.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

But I am having `colorMain` and `listTextColor` in colors.xml

**EDIT**
colors.xml

`<color name="colorMain">#fff</color>
<color name="listTextColor">#fff</color>`

I used here:

```
  `<EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittxtPassword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="45dp"
                android:background="@color/listTextColor"
                android:hint="Enter your Password"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="10"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:paddingLeft="45dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp" />`
```

Comment: Paste how you defined colorMain and listTextColor in colors.xml

Comment: Could you paste the colors.xml ? And where do you refer the color ?

Comment: @santak pls see edit

Comment: can you paste the snippet where you are calling these ?

Comment: @warl0ck pls see edited question

Comment: Maybe an IDE bug, Try `invalidate and restart` ?

Comment: @RustFisher please tell me how to invalidate?

Comment: File -> invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: @RustFisher again it shows the error some problem

Comment: Well it is really strange... Could you post your gradle and the path of your color.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is there is an entry for `colorMain` and `listTextcolor` in styles.xml

Then I deleted the entry, and rebuild. Build was Successful.

Answer (score 2):

create "color" folder in res  directory, add color resource file and define color like this in color xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/black" />
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```